# How to show "Turn left" "Turn right" messages on the route highlighted between two places on Google map?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, google-maps, map-directions

I'm developing an application in which I need to display a message showing where to turn after user clicks a position on route highlighted with the help of directions on Google map.

There's this Groute class which provides much of the information like distance, duration between two places, but it doesn't give information about direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the GRoute you can use .getStep(i) to obtain the GStep object for each step in the GRoute. .getNumSteps() tells you how many GSteps are in a GRoute.

For each GStep you can call .getDescriptionHtml() which will return the formatted description for that individual step. Like "Take the 1st **right** onto **A5099/Coronation St**" or "At the roundabout, take the **3rd** exit onto **A6/Garstang Rd** heading to **Preston**".

To relate the GStep to a specific vertex of the polyline, scan through all the GSteps looking for the last one with a getPolylineIndex() that's less than or equal to the specified vertex. Like this:

```
      var v = 66; // The vertex you are looking for

      var targetStep = route.getStep(0);
      for (var j=0; j<route.getNumSteps(); j++) {
        var step = route.getStep(j);
        if (step.getPolylineIndex() < v) targetStep = step;
      }
      GLog.writeHtml(targetStep.getDescriptionHtml());
```

Don't attempt to parse the .getDescriptionHtml() because the details of the structure change from time to time and vary depending on the country of the route and the host language or locale.

Comment: Thanx Mike Williams.. Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Mike Williams, I tried implementing all the steps you pointed out. But I'm stuck at the step of relating GStep to a specific vertex of the polyline. I'm not getting the meaning of "scan through all the GSteps looking for the last one with a getPolylineIndex() that's less than or equal to the specified vertex". Can you please help me?

Comment: I've edited a code sample into the Answer because I don't know if it's possible to do formatted text inside a Comment.

Comment: Mike Williams : Thank you very much for piece of code. I am an iOS developer and has been facing the same issue in iOS app on which i am working right now. Has been looking for this solution for more than 3 days. This answer cleared my logic on how to implement the same. Thanx once again. :)